# Deadlock between Parallel.Invoke and Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library, dispatcher

I am fairly new to WPF and parallel processing. I have converted a simple program from Console app to WPF. There are few functions which I want to execute in parallel. Below code runs fine in a Console app.

```
long primeP;
string[] arrIDsP = null;
string[] arrNamesP = null;
string[] arrMergedP = null;

Parallel.Invoke(
    () => primeP = this.FindPrimeNumber(Convert.ToInt64(txtPrime.Text)),
    () => arrIDsP = this.FetchData(@txtFilePath1.Text),
    () => arrNamesP = this.FetchData(@txtFilePath2.Text));

arrMergedP = this.MergeIDToNameP(arrIDsP, arrNamesP);
```

When I use the same in a WPF, I get exception-

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it

So I used Dispather.Invoke as per suggestions across other Stackoverflow posts-

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => primeP = this.FindPrimeNumber(this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Convert.ToInt64(txtPrime.Text))),
    () => arrIDsP = this.FetchData(this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => @txtFilePath1.Text)),
    () => arrNamesP = this.FetchData(this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => @txtFilePath2.Text)));

arrMergedP = this.MergeIDToNameP(arrIDsP, arrNamesP);
```

Now the problem is my code gets stuck infinitely inside the Parallel.Invoke. After searching I came across this link- [Cannot use Dispatcher.Invoke in Parallel.Invoke](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c5d3f40-6046-464f-8fc1-89eed3ff35f1/cannot-use-dispatcherinvoke-in-parallelinvoke?forum=csharplanguage) and it seems like a deadlock issue.

I know I can assign the text box values in separate variables and pass them as parameters and then use Parallel.Invoke but what would be the workaround if I don't use the variables?

Can someone please suggest a proper way to resolve this?

Comment: The only proper way is stay away from accessing the UI from any background thread because that work has to be done on the UI thread. Forcing a backgroundthread to do that will create a context switch to the UI thread! Don't try to beat the system.

Comment: In any proper way to resolve this you will need to first save UI data to variables (like already answered). Not sure why exactly you are trying to avoid doing this (quite reasonable) thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not work on WPF directly, but the error is clearly indicative. Since each of the parameter of Parallel.Invoke executes on a thread, try accessing the values from WPF user interface (e.g. textPrime.Text) outside of those threads.

```
long primeP;
string[] arrIDsP = null;
string[] arrNamesP = null;
string[] arrMergedP = null;

string prime = txtPrime.Text;
string filePath1 = txtFilePath1.Text;
string filePath2 = txtFilePath2.Text;

Parallel.Invoke(
    () => primeP = this.FindPrimeNumber(Convert.ToInt64(prime)),
    () => arrIDsP = this.FetchData(filePath1),
    () => arrNamesP = this.FetchData(filePath2));

arrMergedP = this.MergeIDToNameP(arrIDsP, arrNamesP);
```

Comment: I know this can work. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh you might get it to work but it will bring you nothing. Safely accessing UI objects from other threads can only be done by executing those instructions on the UI thread, that is what Dispacher.Invoke can do but it will switch from background thread to UI thread effectively rendering you 'parallel' execution useless.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel.Invoke method blocks calling thread until all operations will be completed. If you call Parallel.Invoke from UI thread and then inside Parallel.Invoke use Dispatcher.Invoke which tries to invoke UI thread, you'll get deadlock, because of Parallel.Invoke method will not be able to complete. The possible solution is to wrap Parallel.Invoke in a Task.Run to relieve the UI thread.